# Communication between GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, reference

I have three classes where i create objects that are JPanels ie MyObject extends JPanel. I call all three panels in a main method call.

```
 MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1(); // contains a textfield and a button
 MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(); // contains a textarea holding a long paragraph
 MyObject3 mo3 = new MyObject3();
```

How can I get mo1 to call methods on mo2 changing the text of the text area?

Thanks for all the suggestions guys! I am gonna go ahead and accept the first answer. It solved my problem.

**Update**
One of these panels was a combination of another two panels in my program, which was hindering my ability to pass an instance of an object to a certain class. By removing that panel class and just creating a jpanel in main then adding the two panels to the new jpanel i was able to pass the instances of the classes to each constructor.

So in turn my solution was

```
JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel(); // create a panel in my main instead of a new class
MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(); // contains a textarea holding a long paragrah
MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1(mo2); // contains a textfield and a button
panelHolder.add(mo1);
panelHolder.add(mo2);
MyObject3 mo3 = new MyObject3();
```

and then in mo2 class:

```
private MyObject1 object1;

// constructor for mo2 Class
public MyObject2(MyObject1 object1){

this.object1 = object1; // to get the instance of object1
....// other constructor pieces
}
```

again thanks guys!

Comment: How are you handling the events? I'm assuming that mo1 has an event-handler for when you press the button.

Comment: yes, i created an ActionListener for the button the sets a textfield to the name of a file that you open using the button. but i then want to give the other Jpanel the entire file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pass a reference to a `MyObject1` instance to the constructor of `MyObject2`?

```
 MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1();
 MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(mo1);
```

Then, (assuming your method is public or package-private) you can simply call `mo1.methodName()` from `mo2`. As I mentioned in comments, you should instantiate any components you plan to edit in `mo1` in its constructor, to avoid NullPointerExceptions when you make the call from `mo2`.

Comment: I tried creating the constructor with the instance of my other panel, but when i did that i get a null pointer exception when trying to change the text.

Comment: You will need to instantiate whatever component your editing in the constructor, before it gets edited by the other class.

Answer (score 1):

How about passing a reference of `MyObject1` to `MyObject2`?

```
public class MyObject2 extends JPanel
{
    private MyObject1 obj;

    public MyObject2(MyObject1 obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

and then your code will be like this:

```
MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1();
MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(mo1);
```

---

- What if you want each class has a reference to the other?
- Simple. Just add a setter in `MyObject1` like:

```
public class MyObject1 extends JPanel
{
    private MyObject2 obj;

    public MyObject1()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void setMyObject2Reference(MyObject2 obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1();
MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(mo1);
mo1.setMyObject2Reference(mo2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1(); // contains a textfield and a button
 MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(); // contains a textarea holding a long paragrah
 MyObject3 mo3 = new MyObject3();
```

Change it to

```
 MyObject2 mo2 = new MyObject2(); // contains a textarea holding a long paragrah
 MyObject1 mo1 = new MyObject1(m02); // contains a textfield and a button
 MyObject3 mo3 = new MyObject3();
```

Then you can call like mo1.getM02().updateText("test");